# How to make ReactPlayer scale with height and width

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe

I am using reactplayer for a youtube video which uses iframe. I am trying to scale the video to my div and I want it to be responsive.

I put a `width` and `height` at `100%` on the ReactPlayer, and I have a wrapper div that I put height and width on, but the reactplayer does not fit the div. It is stuck at a height of 150px no matter how I resize the screen.

```
<div className="video-wrapper>
  <ReactPlayer
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            url="https://youtu.be/BGhqlJnFIXU"
            controls
            muted
            config={{
              youtube: {
                playerVars: { showinfo: 1 }
              }
            }}
          />
</div>
```

.css

```
.video-wrapper {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 225px;
}
```

Comment: For a more comprehensive solution, see https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/145

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by further-extending your CSS.  Since most videos are shot in 16:9, following [this guide by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) will make the process easily achievable.

Since you're utilizing React-Player, I am working with the content located on their [demo page](https://cookpete.com/react-player/).

```
.player-wrapper {
  width: auto; // Reset width
  height: auto; // Reset height
}
.react-player {
  padding-top: 56.25%; // Percentage ratio for 16:9
  position: relative; // Set to relative
}

.react-player > div {
  position: absolute; // Scaling will occur since parent is relative now
}
```

**Why it works?**

TL;DR - Padding in percentages is *based on width*.  By setting an element's height to 0, we can utilize a percentage for 'padding-top' to scale content perfectly.

**Generate 16:9's Percentage**

(9 / 16) * 100 = 56.25

Comment: there is a issue where the parent of `.player-wrapper` is having 0 width in some cases...
my case i set the with of the parent of  `.player-wrapper` to 100% and it was good.

Comment: I'd like to point out this hack is now redundant with the advent of the css "aspect-ratio: 16/9;" on a wrapper div your woes will disappear.

Comment: @nrmad Not completely redundant due to browser support, unfortunately. Aspect-ratio works fine for most browsers, but you'll still want to leverage CSS supports as a fallback if you're looking to achieve a universal experience.

`@supports not (aspect-ratio: 1 / 1) { // add CSS hack here }`

Comment: Working perfectly but I also had to add `top: 0;` to the `.react-player > div` selector for my case.

Comment: But it does not work for light prop to show thumbnail

Answer (score 13):

To force react-player be fully responsive I did the following:

CSS

```css
.player-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 720 / 1280 = 0.5625 */
}

.react-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

JSX

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import "./Player.css";

const Player = () => (
  <div className="player-wrapper">
    <ReactPlayer
      url="https://youtu.be/3eLrINg3O2Q"
      className="react-player"
      playing
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      controls={false}
    />
  </div>
);

export default Player;
```

Comment: Followed your advice (using CSS modules) - the wrapper takes up the space but the player does not appear..

Comment: I tried it again - working great. Check you code. Check example https://jsfiddle.net/e6w3rtj1/

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Easiest way to make the it responsive is adding the widht as 100%

```
<ReactPlayer
  controls
  pip
  width="100%"
  url={_post.videolink}
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

For a more modern approach, just add a class to the react player component and set it to:

```
height: auto !important;
aspect-ratio: 16/9;
```

https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

Comment: Yep. Why it is not the best answer ? 

Answer (score 2):

you can fill with:

```
 .react-player > video {
   position: absolute;
   object-fit: fill;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tailwindcss and Swiper you can use this code

This code implements the last aspect-video class to ensure the aspect ratio always be correct

And also ensure that if the user scroll to the next page, the previous player gets paused

You can also set Max width of videos , here its "max-w-6xl"

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Pagination } from "swiper";
const videos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234"
  }
];

const IndexHero = () => {
  const [domLoaded, setDomLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setDomLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <div className='h-auto'>
      {!domLoaded && (
        <div className="flex items-start justify-center">
          <div className="flex-1 max-w-6xl">
            <div className="aspect-video">
            {/** For CLS */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      {domLoaded && (
      <Swiper
          modules={[Pagination]} 
          pagination={true} 
          className="h-full "
          onSlideChange={() => {
            setIsPlaying(null);
          }}
          autoplay={false}
          watchSlidesProgress={true}
        >
          {videos.map((data) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={data.id}>

              <div className="flex items-start justify-center">
                <div className="flex-1 max-w-6xl"> 
                  <div className="aspect-video">
                  <ReactPlayer
                      key={data.id}
                      url={data.url}
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      controls={true}
                      onPlay={() => {
                        setIsPlaying(data.id);
                      }}
                      playing={isPlaying === data.id}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>              
            </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper> )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexHero;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the width fixed and then allow the height to adjust according to the video height as different video has its own size like 100*200.
`.video-wrapper > video { width: 55vw; height: min-content; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy fix that works for me, I hope it do it for you too

```
  const videoRef = useRef<ReactPlayer>(null!)

  const beginningHandler = () => {
    const videoTag = videoRef.current.getInternalPlayer() as HTMLVideoElement;
    videoTag.style.objectFit = 'cover';
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }}>
      <ReactPlayer
        ref={videoRef}
        volume={1}
        onEnded={() => console.log('finish')}
        url={'./videos/time-travel.mp4'}
        width={'100%'}
        height={'100%'}
        playing
        onStart={beginningHandler}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I did it.

```
video { object-fit: cover; }
```

Now, the size of the video can be adjusted by sizing the wrapper.